# How to install a swift framework which has a cocoapod dependency into your swift app project in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I've looked all over for an example on this and couldn't really find something that matches my question/situation.

I have a swift framework called FrameworkA. Within FrameworkA I have placed a cocoapod, Alamofire, by creating a podfile and adding the needed pod information. The podfile is listed next.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FrameworkA' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for FrameworkA
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.2'
end
```

The pod/Alamofire installs correctly as I tested it using a simple call in a test class within FrameworkA. See code:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class TestClass {
    
    let test = AF.request("https:/google.com").response { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
    
}
```

With everything working, at this point I would like to place FrameworkA inside a Swift App project within Xcode.

This is where I run into a roadblock as i am unable to build a simple app ApplicationA with FrameworkA installed as Alamofire is not found within FrameworkA. See image.

[image: module not found]

### What I have tried:

I have tried dragging and dropping in FrameworkA's .xcodeproj file into ApplicationA's project within Xcode and then adding the framework to Frameworks, Libraries, Embedded Content section. See images.
[image: module drag and drop]

[image]

When I try to build I get a compile error that FrameworkA cannot find Alamofire. See image:

[image]

My main questions is:

- How do I get ApplicationA to build successfully as obviously Alamofire is not getting installed along with the framework?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer my own question.

All I had to do was add Alamofire to ApplicationA as a cocoapod and everything builds correctly.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'ApplicationA' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ApplicationA
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.2'
end
```

Comment: Is there another way to avoid main app pod integration? Thanks